# Best way to handle incoming messages with XMPP

Tags: xmpp, spring-integration

Is there a work-around to get Spring to handle incoming messages from XMPP?  I have tried many different configurations to get an inbound-channel-adapter to respond to incoming XMPP messages and nothing happens.  I know that they show up at the Spring Integration layer (I can see that in the logs) but they are ignored.  Is there any way to get them into my application layer? I hope to avoid needing to make changes to Spring Integration itself if I can.

Here is my integration configuration:

```
<int-xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter id="gcmIn" 
                                      channel="gcmInChannel"
                                      xmpp-connection="gcmConnection"
                                      auto-startup="true"
    />
    <bean id="inboundBean" class="example.integration.GcmInputHandler"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="gcmInChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" ref="inboundBean" method="handle"/>
```

Using the outbound-channel-adapter works fine.  I can send messages over GCM 100% easily.  But inbound does nothing, even though I know the messages are coming in.

Thanks

Comment: Please, share your logs and even better test-case to reproduce. Maybe your issue that you send them to the `nullChannel` after your `inboundBean` ?

Comment: I found out what was going wrong.  It was quite a complicated issue.  Basically, Spring Integration silently drops XMPP messages that are empty.  When GCM sends a message over XMPP, the message content is in an extension, not in the body, so Spring Integration thinks the message is empty and it is silently dropped.  It never leaves the inbound channel adapter.  I looked in the source code and there is no logging when the message is dropped, making this problem impossible to see at any level of logging.  I may publish a guide with all the steps I had to go through to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very clean one, you would need to overwrite the ChatMessageListeningEndpoint, which drops all empty body messages. 
This one needs then to be used as inbound-channel adapter in your config.

In addition you need to register the GCM package extension on the Smack Provider Manager, otherwise you lose the JSON message.

Working on a sample project -- so if you need more help let me know and I will post a link as soon it works somehow in a understandable way.

Here a sample GCM Input Adapter

```
    public class GcmMessageListeningEndpoint extends ChatMessageListeningEndpoint {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GcmMessageListeningEndpoint.class);
    @Setter
    protected PacketListener packetListener = new GcmPacketListener();
    protected XmppHeaderMapper headerMapper = new DefaultXmppHeaderMapper();

    public GcmMessageListeningEndpoint(XMPPConnection connection) {
        super(connection);


        ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(GcmPacketExtension.GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GcmPacketExtension.GCM_NAMESPACE,
                new PacketExtensionProvider() {
                    @Override
                    public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception {
                        String json = parser.nextText();
                        return new GcmPacketExtension(json);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeaderMapper(XmppHeaderMapper headerMapper) {
        super.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);
        this.headerMapper = headerMapper;
        if (this.headerMapper == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null XmppHeaderMapper isn't supported!");
    }

    public String getComponentType() {
        return "xmpp:inbound-channel-adapter-gcm";
    }

    @Override
    protected void doStart() {
        Assert.isTrue(this.initialized, this.getComponentName() + " [" + this.getComponentType() + "] must be initialized");
        this.xmppConnection.addPacketListener(this.packetListener, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doStop() {
        if (this.xmppConnection != null) {
            this.xmppConnection.removePacketListener(this.packetListener);
        }
    }

    class GcmPacketListener implements PacketListener {

        @Override
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) throws NotConnectedException {
            if (packet instanceof org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message) {
                org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message xmppMessage = (org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message) packet;
                Map<String, ?> mappedHeaders = headerMapper.toHeadersFromRequest(xmppMessage);
                sendMessage(MessageBuilder.withPayload(xmppMessage).copyHeaders(mappedHeaders).build());
            } else {
                LOG.warn("Unsuported Packet {}", packet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here the new configuration for the **inbound-channel-adapter** remove the one in XML:

```
@Bean 
public GcmMessageListeningEndpoint inboundAdpater(XMPPConnection connection, MessageChannel gcmInChannel) {
    GcmMessageListeningEndpoint endpoint = new GcmMessageListeningEndpoint(connection);
    endpoint.setOutputChannel(gcmInChannel);
    return endpoint;
}
```

Comment: A working code sample can be found here: https://github.com/puel/training/tree/master/gcm